# handling several pipes with fork

Tags: c, process, pipe, fork

I have to do a very simple shell that takes a single command as arguments, e.g:

`./a.out "/bin/ls" "|" "/usr/bin/grep/" "m" "|" "/usr/bin/grep" "u"`

The command will always be valid (no syntax error), and I only have to handle pipes.
I already have my ast working, but I have an issue with the execution part.
Here's my ast structure:

```
struct      s_ast
{
    int     t;   // type (either PIPE or CMD)
    t_ast   *l;  // left node (or NULL it t == CMD)
    t_ast   *r;  // right node (or NULL it t == CMD)
    char    **c; // the command with its args (or NULL if t == PIPE)
};
```

And here's the code of the execution part:

```
void exe_pipe(t_ast *ast, char **env)
{
    int fd[2], pid = 0;

    if (pipe(fd) < 0 || (pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        error(NULL, NULL);
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        exe(ast->l, env);
        exit(0);
    }
    // EDIT: I don't fork anymore for the right side of a PIPE node
    dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);
    exe(ast->r, env);
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
}
```

It works well and for every simple command, I get the expected result, but if I give a big command with a lot of pipes, I get the `Error: fork error` message. In order to test it, I used `ulimit -Su 300` to reduce the max authorized number of processes running at the same time, and I passed a command with a hundred pipes to the program.

I tried several things but I can't figure out how I could input a command with more pipes than the max number of allowed processes.

Comment: Please explain in a bit more detail, because it now appears to me that you're trying to spawn more processes than the kernel allows and that you are surprised.

Comment: My program must be able to execute a command with more pipes than processes allowed by the kernel yep, So I think I'm waiting for childs at the wrong place, or maybe I don't need to fork for the right side of the pipe but everything I tried failed

Comment: I suggest you look at `errno` after the fork fails.

Comment: With errno, I get the error 35, which output `Resource temporarily unavailable` with strerror, because of too much processes running simulteanously.

Comment: Yet you seem to think you should be able to spawn more processes while you clearly can't.

Comment: Yes it is, you are right, its not possible. Just figured out that even bash don't handle that much pipes. So my school project is undoable